# Xcode integration in Jenkins - permission denied

Tags: xcode, jenkins

i'm trying to built my Xcode Projekt with Jenkins, but when i built i get the error

```
Started by user anonymous Building in workspace /Users/icash/.jenkins/jobs/first-ios-app/workspace JDK installation 
skipped: Unknown CPU name: mac os x Checkout:workspace / /Users/icash/.jenkins/jobs/first-ios-app/workspace - 
hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@13ed9bc5 Using strategy: Default Last Built Revision: 
Revision abc22103fa068c103fabf76999ec03d8710957f4 (origin/master) 
Checkout:workspace / /Users/icash/.jenkins/jobs/first-ios-app/workspace - 
hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@13ed9bc5 Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository Fetching upstream changes 
from git://github.com/shinetech/jenkins-ios-example.git Commencing build of Revision 
abc22103fa068c103fabf76999ec03d8710957f4 (origin/master) Checking out Revision abc22103fa068c103fabf76999ec03d8710957f4 
(origin/master) JDK installation skipped: Unknown CPU name: mac os x Working directory is 
/Users/icash/.jenkins/jobs/first-ios-app/workspace [workspace] $ /users/icash/dev/ -version FATAL: Cannot run program 
"/users/icash/dev/" (in directory "/Users/icash/.jenkins/jobs/first-ios-app/workspace"): error=13, Permission denied 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/users/icash/dev/" (in directory 
"/Users/icash/.jenkins/jobs/first-ios-app/workspace"): error=13, Permission denied  
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)  at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)  
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)  at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:707)  
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:338)     at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:345)  
at au.com.rayh.XCodeBuilder.perform(XCodeBuilder.java:120)  
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)    
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:703)    
at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.build(Build.java:178)  
at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.doRun(Build.java:139)  
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:473)    
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1410)  
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)  
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)  
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:238) Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied     
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)     
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:53)    
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:91)     
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
```

although i gave .jenkins folder all permission.

Comment: Please post more of the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that it is trying to run a directory (`/users/icash/dev/`) as if it is an app. Seems something is configured incorrectly. Search for `/users/icash/dev/` in your top-level *config.xml*; if not found search for a pattern `${var_name}/dev`. If not found there, look in *config.xml* for your job.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your build step looks like:

```
/users/icash/dev/$SOMEVARIABLE -version
```

and SOMEVARIABLE is not defined in the environment where Jenkins is running. That is why it expands into an empty string. What is left is the path to a directory and you cannot execute that.

If you need some environment variables in Jenkins, you can set them by going to Jenkins UI -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System. Then add environment variables there.